# jQuery ui Tabs get href

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm at the moment using jQuery UI. I've trying to do some tabs..

```
<div id="tabs" style="width:18%; height:30%; float:right">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#first" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;">My_first</a></li>
            <li><a href="#second" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;">My_second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#third" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;">My_third</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fourth" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;">My_fourth</a></li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

.. and it's work.

But now, I would like when I click on a tabs this :

alert("You click on the tab called " + href of tab);

How can I do this?

```
//catch on change

    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function() {
            console.log($("#tabs").tabs(/* ?? */)); // doesn't working atm
        }
    });
```

I'm sure it's pretty easy.

Ty!

Answer (score 4):

You can access the new tab using the `newTab` property of `ui` argument as follows:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
  activate: function (e, ui) {
    console.log(ui.newTab.find("a").attr("href"));
  }
});
```

```js
$("#tabs").tabs({
  activate: function(e, ui) {
    console.log(ui.newTab.find("a").attr("href"));
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs" style="width:18%; height:30%; float:right">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="first" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;">My_first</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="second" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;">My_second</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="third" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;">My_third</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="fourth" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;">My_fourth</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following event to get current url:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  beforeActivate: function(event, ui){
     alert('You clicked: ' + $(ui.tab).attr('href'));
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs" style="width:18%; height:30%; float:right">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#first" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;" class="TabLink">My_first</a></li>
            <li><a href="#second" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;" class="TabLink">My_second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#third" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;" class="TabLink">My_third</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fourth" style="font-size:9px; text-align:center;" class="TabLink">My_fourth</a></li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".TabLink").click(function(){
    alert("You clicked on the tab called " + $(this).prop("href"));    
});
```

Comment: ty it's works ! I don't know why I didn't try it with jQuery and a class.

Comment: Thanks - I'm glad that it works!  On this site, when an answer is useful for you, you should vote it up by clicking the up arrow next to it.  That's how people get points and it's how others who later visit this thread can quickly identify the most useful answers without having to read through and test all of them.